# Fluent nHibernate Auto Mapping - Issue with AutoMapping Override

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, automapping

I've just tried to get a project up and running with Fluent Automapping (I'm familiar with Fluent but used to write each of the maps)

I have an object ScriptType which has a ParseRules property

```
public class ScriptType : EntityBase
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<ParseRule> ParseRules { get; set; }
}
```

This is being Auto Mapped as HasMany and I wanted References.

I therefore added an AutoMapping override to another assembly ...

```
public class ScriptTypeOverride : IAutoMappingOverride<ScriptType>
{
    public void Override(AutoMapping<ScriptType> mapping)
    {
        mapping.References(x => x.ParseRules);
    }
}
```

And altered my configuration as so ...

```
return configuration
            .Mappings(m => m.AutoMappings
                               .Add(AutoMap.AssemblyOf<DatabaseInfo>()
                                        .IgnoreBase<EntityBase>()
                                        .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<KeyConvention>()
                                        .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<ScriptTypeOverride>()));
```

But I get this ....  :(

An association from the table ScriptType refers to an unmapped class: System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[GIT.ScriptWizard.Entities.ParseRule ...

Can anyone help please?

Comment: If you have a list of ParseRules, you can't use References.  References is for a single object reference, not a collection.  A collection like IList<> needs a HasMany.

Comment: Thanks Carl, you're right - I'd misunderstood what references was for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `References` is for creating many-to-one
>   relationships between two entities,
>   and is applied on the "many side."
>   You're referencing a single other
>   entity, so you use the `References`
>   method. `HasMany` is the "other side" of
>   the `References` relationship, and gets
>   applied on the "one side."

From [Fluent's website](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping#References_.2F_many-to-one).

How should your relation work? It looks like a classic one `ScriptType`-to-many `ParseRules`, so this should be `HasMany` on `ScriptType`'s side, as Fluent does.

Maybe, if you want to have bidirectional relationship here, where `ParseRule`'s side is the "owning" side of the relation, you should use `Inverse()` in `ScriptType.ParseRules` mapping override.

Comment: I'd got it into my head that References was doing something else!  I've added a HasManyToMany override and its all come good, thank you